# Values of parameter such that $y$ satisfies DE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

For what values of k does $y= 5 + 3e^{kx}$ satisfy the differential equation

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = 10 - 2y $$

Hey i normally post stuff i know about the subject but i don't really get where to start here sorry.

Comment: **Hint**: What is $\frac{dy}{dx}$ when $y=5+3e^{kx}$?

Answer (score 4):

Plug in. The derivative is $3ke^{kx}$, and $10-2y=-6e^{kx}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since

$$y= 5 + 3e^{kx}$$ $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx} y = \frac{d}{dx} \left( 5  + 3e^{kx} \right) $$

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = 6ke^{kx} .... (1) $$

And as given
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = 10 - 2y  $$ where again $y= 5 + 3e^{kx}$

dy/dx is hence.... 
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = 10 - 2(5 + 3e^{kx}) = 3e^{kx}  $$

As we have also found out the $\frac{dy}{dx} = 6ke^{kx}$
$$6ke^{kx}= 3e^{kx}$$

if k = 2 and k = -2 then y would satisfy the equation

Comment: I suppose some typo's : $\frac{dy}{dx} = 3ke^{kx}$ first. I let you fixing your answer (by the way, from your last equation, how could you find $k=\pm 2$ ?)